# Sudo complains “is not in the sudoers file”

Tags: sudo

I try to install Chrome and Skype on Debian. [image: Data about my laptop]

When I'm trying to install from the terminal, or log in as administrator, even when I type the correct password, every time I receive a error.
What am I doing wrong?

> ravenous is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

[image: Wrong password in terminal?]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Copy-paste the text. Screenshots are hard to read and cannot be searched.

Answer (score 5):

Add an entry into `/etc/sudoers` to permit user ravenous to run dpkg as root.

See man page for `sudo` for more detail.

Comment: Use `visudo` to edit the file.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to execute commands as the administrator: with [su](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)) or with [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). The su command requires the root password, and can be used by any user who knows the root password. The sudo command asks for your own password, and can only be used by users who have been authorized by the administrator. (Both commands can be configured differently, I'm describing the default configuration.)

If you set a root password during installation, then you can use `su` to run commands as root, for example

```
su -c 'dpkg -i google-chrome*deb'
```

If you want to use sudo, you'll first need to your account to the list of users allowed to use it. Under Debian, all users in the group called `sudo` can run any command as any user via the `sudo` command. So add your account to the `sudo` group:

```
su -c 'addgroup ravenous sudo'
```

You can do that through the GUI (in the “Users” settings tool) if you prefer. Group assignments take effect when you log in, so you'll need to log out and back in.

Comment: You may need to use /usr/sbin/addgroup in some cases

Answer (score 1):

Log into root with the su command.
check your users groups with the command "groups ravenous" (note groups)

edit /etc/sudoers with, for example nano or vi "vi /etc/sudoers" scroll down to the part where you see groups that are uncommented (no # in front) and see if you are in that group (which your obviously are not)

if any group is allowed you need to add your user to the group. if you cant see any uncommented groups, you need to uncomment a group.

Uncomment:
if using vi, press i for insert, move with keypads to the # in front of the group you need to uncomment, remove the hashtag. 
press esc and type :wq! to write and quit.

Now, you add your user to the group:
usermod -a -G wheel ravenous (add ravenous to group wheel)
Log out as root, log out as ravenous, log back in. Or reboot if u'd like that.

Comment: Don't edit `/etc/sudoers` directly! Run the command `visudo`.

Comment: Indeed, better to use visudo.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply add ravenous to the sudo group. Login as root or use su. Then to add the user to the sudo group use this:

```
usermod -aG sudo ravenous
```

A default install of the sudo package on most Linux systems already have the group sudo setup for access (I know debian does as thats what I use myself), so simply adding any username to that group will grant access to use sudo. Also you will need to relogin for the change to take affect.

Comment: It wouldn't work if the logged-in user just typed `newgrp sudo`?

Comment: hmm, good question, I am unsure whether that will make the new sudo group your default, or just add it as another group your belong to. Reading the man for this seems to indicate that would work though.

Answer (score 0):

> ### How to add user to the list of sudo users.

(Debian 9 Stretch)

First. From terminal, type: `visudo`

Find:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Directly underneath these lines, add your user name:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
newName ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Exit visudo:

`ctrl` + `x`

Save changes to file:

`Y`

Enter.

Reboot.

New terminal:

```
$   sudo apt-get update
```

At prompt, type password

Finished. You should now be using a 'regular' account user with sudo privileges.